# iftop how to use?

Tags: networking

Iftop is what I downloaded to see my daily internet usage of my computer or any other computer on my LAN (ie bro and sisters usage).  I want  total MB's/day from each computer.  so I installed and ran sudo iftop and I get a screen  just like the website says I should except,  no domains or IP's or anything, its an empty chart.  **Is there a command I have to tell it to monitor my local network?**  I know there's activity I am surfing right now. Yes I read the webpage, no I did not glean a how to use, so it must be that "common knowledge" thing I am missing.

Comment: You are using wired or wireless? And I think for your purposes `vnstat` is needed, not `iftop`.

Comment: thanks Jack Jefferson
this worked with me it was sudo iftop -i wlp2s0

Answer (score 9):

iftop display Network Interface Bandwidth Usage.  To install iftop if not installed, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install iftop
```

By default iftop command displays the bandwidth usage of the first available Ethernet device.

```
sudo iftop
```

Or you can also specify an interface using the -i option.

```
sudo iftop -i eth0
```

While iftop is running, you can press any one of the following keys to display more output.

```
S - display source port
D - display destination port
n - show IP instead of host name
1/2/3 - sort by the specified column
< - sort by source name
> - sort by destination name
P - pause display ( else it will be often updated to show the current status )
j/k - scroll display
? - for help
```

The image below shows the different arguments (options) that you can use with iftop.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Iftop is probably set up to use a different network interface. Run the command `ifconfig` to see your connections. Then if, for example, your connection is named `eth0` run the command `sudo iftop -i eth0`. Hope this solved your problem.

Comment: this worked, thank you Jack Jefferson.  and thank you  Mitch for taking the time to respond.  "sudo iftop -i wlan0" gave the desired result.  also used the "-p" option.  Now all I need to know is how do I do the highlighting code that shows the commands like you do.

Comment: `code` is typed with a ` either side. That's the key above tab (on a standard UK keyboard), not an apostrophe.